# C# Cast Class to Overridden Class

Tags: c#, class, overriding

I have a class `Application` that I need to override with INotifyPropertyChanged events.  I have written the logic to override the original class and ended up creating `SuperApplication`

I am pulling the data from a library though, and cannot change the loading logic.  I just need a way to get the data from the original class into my superClass.  I've tried things like `superClass = (SuperApplication)standardClass;` but it hasn't worked.

How would I go about doing this?

If it helps, this is the code I'm using to override the original class:

```
public class SuperCreditApplication : CreditApplication
{
    public SuperCreditApplicant Applicant { get; set; }
    public SuperCreditApplicant CoApplicant { get; set; }
}

public class SuperCreditApplicant : CreditApplicant
{
    public SuperProspect Prospect { get; set; }
}

public class SuperProspect : Prospect, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public State DriverLicenseState
    {
        get
        {
            return DriverLicenseState;
        }
        set
        {
            DriverLicenseState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DriverLicenseState");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code (or a sample of the code) from `Application` and `SuperApplication`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a copy constructor, passing in "the data from the original class" as a parameter to a newly-constructed `superClass` (Incidentally, I think the name `Super`- is probably a mistake, as that will make people think that it's *above* the original in the hierarchy).

By copy-constructor, I mean something like:

```
class IWishIWasntCalledSuperApplication : Application 
{
  IWishIWasntCalledSuperApplication(Application original) 
  { 
      this.someData = original.someData;
      this.someOtherData = original.someOtherData;
      ...etc...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can't just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly on `Prospect`.  If you cannot directly change `Prospect` (like make all your properties `virtual`), you can make your `SuperProspect` class a wrapper for `Prospect`

```
public class SuperProspect : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Prospect _prospect;

    public SuperProspect(Prospect prospect)
    {
        _prospect = prospect;
    }

    public State DriverLicenseState
    {
        get { return _prospect.DriverLicenseState; }
        set
        {
            _prospect.DriverLicenseState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DriverLicenseState");
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _prospect.SomeMethod();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `SuperProspect` like this

```
var superProspect = new SuperProspect(myProspect);
```

If you create an interface for your `Prospect` members, then you can make both your `SuperProspect` and your `Prospect` implement the same interface. If you then program to the interface rather than the concrete `Prospect` implementation, your code will work with both `SuperProspect` and/or `Prospect`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment and edit I need to give a new answer lol - i misunderstood

you need to use interception to add the event handlers to the properties over which you have no control maybe. Personally I ahve seen this done with IoC containers such as prism.  I may be completley wrong here btw but i think MEF may also help

Another way would be to look into code generation using T4 templates to reflect over the existing class to generate your superclass and the properties that map onto 4existing that would contain the code to fire the events.

this looks like it
http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2009/03/01/implementing-inotifyproperychanged-with/

To explain the MEF thing: I am pretty sure i have seen INotifyPropertyChanged hooked up using MEF in various silverlight examples. I wasn't interested in that aspect when i was reading though so didn't read up on it.

Extracting an interface and using an ioc container to do all the heavy lifting would be the shortest route i imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether the load was during the construction of the object or a later method call. Depending on which, it would look like one of these two code samples.

```
//This constructor signature should match your base class's
public SuperCreditApplication(object a, object b, object c) : base(a,b,c)
{
    //Do whatever you need to do here. The base object's constructor will be called for you
}

public Load()
{
    this.BaseObjectLoadMethod();
}
```

Then you make a new `SuperCreditApplication` and work with that.